# Silverlight how to promote selected item of listbox when using buttons within datatemplates

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, listbox, datatemplate

Within a Listbox control I have a Data Template which consists of text and a button. Given the nature of Silverlight/WPF when I click on the button within the listbox item the button event is trapped before the listbox item is selected. Therefore if I am trying to pass the record ID of the selected listbox item I am currently only able to do so by first clicking and selecting the listbox item and then clicking on the button.

Is there a way to promote the selection of the listbox item so that when the listbox items are created I have the ability to click on the button within the listbox item and some event (selectionChanged ?) is invoked which would allow me to capture the selected record id and use it for some other action ( pass as a parameter in a method etc). I'm using Simple MVVM toolkit for this implementation so I was wondering if this could be handled in the viewModel or if I would need to handle this in the controls code behind and then push the selection to the viewModel.

The listbox control is presented as:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ResultListBox"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             Background="{x:Null}"
             Grid.Row="1"
             BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults[0].Results}"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <dts:TypeTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <!--  Template 1  -->
                    <formatter:TypeTemplateSelector.CFSTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <qr:ucIndex_Product />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </formatter:TypeTemplateSelector.CFSTemplate>

                    <!--  Template 2  -->
                    <formatter:TypeTemplateSelector.PersonTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <qr:ucIndex_Person  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </formatter:TypeTemplateSelector.PersonTemplate>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Within the datatemplate (user control) resides the button along with a number of other fields. I'll omit that code for the time being unless requested.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `ListBox.Resources`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" Handler="SelectCurrentItem"/>
</Style>
```

And this in the Code Behind

```
protected void SelectCurrentItem(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;
    item.IsSelected = true;
}
```

You could use the following code as well which doesn't use code-behind, however it only keeps the ListBoxItem selected for as long as it has KeyBoard focus. Once focus leaves, the item becomes unselected

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**EDIT**

Since Silverlight doesn't have EventSetters, you can use the ListBox's Loaded event and add the following to your code behind:

```
private void ResultListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox list = (ListBox)sender;
    list.GotFocus += ResultListBox_GotFocus;
}

void ResultListBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = FindAncester<ListBoxItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
    if (item != null) item.IsSelected = true;
}

T FindAncester<T>(DependencyObject current) 
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current is T)
        {
            return (T)current;
        }
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    };
    return null;
}
```

This captures the Focus event for the ListBox, takes the control that triggered the focus event and traverses up the visual tree to find the `ListBoxItem` objects, and sets it's Selected value to true.

Comment: Event Setters are not available in Silverlight This solution works great for WPF just not for silverlight.

Comment: Hrrm forgot about that. What about just setting the `PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` event in the code-behind of the ListBox's `DataContextChanged` event?

Comment: Silverlight Listbox does not have a DataContextChanged event.

Comment: @randyC lol OK, what about the `Loaded` event? Since this is a web application I am guessing that the Items for the ListBox will be determined before the ListBox is actually loaded on the client's page

Comment: I appreciate your help. This listbox is presenting data based up search results so the list Collection is updated every time a user invokes a new search. Where the trick is in the data template each data template is a user control that contains a number of Ui elements. I should have clarified this before and I have updated my question to show the code.

Comment: @randyc I updated my answer with a Silverlight-version of the code. It sets a ListBoxItem as selected as soon as any object inside that ListBoxItem receives focus.

Comment: I tried you suggestion however this is only fired when the listbox is created it does not propagate to the controls when they load.  Thank you

Comment: @randyc You got me obsessed with finding a problem for this lol. I updated my answer with a syntax that will work with Silverlight.

Comment: That works like a charm Thanks for your help Rachel.  I have a little minor tweaking to push the focus back to the child object once the item is selected but this is a great start.

Answer (score 1):

Rachel's solution works great. The one issue I did find in this approach was that it does place total focus on the selected item. As a result the user would be required to double click within the control to place focus on other items such as selectable text or other button. After working with this a bit more I discovered you can also resolve this by setting the listbox selected items to the data context of the object you are clicking on etc. This works well as allows you to set this to any UI object within the control.

```
   ListBox.SelectedItem = ((HyperlinkButton)sender).DataContext;
```

In this example I had Hyperlink buttons within the data template. Clicking on them would then set the focus to the selected listbox item.

Answer (score 1):

rlcrews got it right! Use DataContext:

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> employees1;
...
listBox1.ItemsSource = employees1;
...

//DataTemplate in ListBox has a button with following event
private void bnPromoteEmployee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Employee emp1 = (Employee)((Button)sender).DataContext;
  emp1.Promote();
}
```